# Mac OS X Sierra default trackpad acceleration value?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

Can anybody quickly tell me the default trackpad acceleration value? I turned off trackpad acceleration but now I want to turn it back on and I don't remember the original value. If you haven't messed with this value on your machine, all you have to do is type in

```
defaults read .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scaling
```

in the terminal and the value will show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scaling
```

will reset to the default value

Answer (score 0):

The command doesn't work me , but this is the value that i have:

[image]

Comment: that's the pointer speed, not the acceleration. I verified that command, it should work, what's going on when you type it in the terminal?

Comment: The domain/default pair of (.GlobalPreferences, com.apple.trackpad.scaling) does not exist

Comment: and you have have Mac OS X Sierra?

Comment: Yes, version 10.12.2 (16C67)

Comment: ah okay, I think i know why its not working. I guess it only works if you change the value. I found that you can type "defaults delete .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scaling" and that will reset to default. Now when I ran the "read" command I asked you to type in, I got the result you're getting. anyway, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Yep, I was try delete to reset to default, but throw me the same result, sorry buddy , I hope someone can help you

Comment: I meant to say the "delete" command successfully resets the value to default. So it's all good, I got what I need.